# Substitution method for solving recurrences - inductive proof

Tags: algorithms, induction, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I have a question regarding section 4.3 in CLRS, in which the following is written:

> We can use the substitution method to establish either upper or lower bounds on a recurrence. As an example, let us determine an upper bound on the recurrence T(n)=2T(n/2)+n. We guess that the solution is O(nlgn). The substitution method requires us to prove that T(n)<=cnlgn for an appropriate choice of the constant c>0.

The proof of the inductive step is:

> $ T(n) ≤ 2(c \frac{n}{2} lg (\frac{n}{2})) + n$
>    $≤cn lg(\frac{n}{2}) + n$
>   $= cn lg n - cn lg 2 + n$
>   $= cn lg n - cn + n$
>    $≤cn lg n,$
>   where the last step holds as long as c >= 1

I omitted the floor notation since it's irrelevant to my question.

**My question**:

As far as I understand, because of the inductive hypothesis for n/2, there is a constant c that satisfies $ T(\frac{n}{2})<= c\frac{n}{2} lg (\frac{n}{2})$ (for n>=n0).

So, shouldn't the inductive step hold for the maximum between **the specific constant c** mentioned above corresponding to the function $T(\frac{n}{2})$, and 1, meaning max{c, 1}?

Thanks in advance!